# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_master_query()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am having a problem when querying my database. I am getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_master_query() in /home/**/**/**/edit/add.php on line 4
```

Here is my PHP code..

```
<?php
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost","XXX","XXX","XXX") or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysqli_master_query($db, "UPDATE users SET order =1 WHERE id =1")){
        echo "Y";
    }else{
        echo "N";
    }
?>
```

Comment: This function has been DEPRECATED and REMOVED as of PHP 5.3.0.

Answer (score 1):

[mysqli_master_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-master-query.php)

```
 This function has been DEPRECATED and REMOVED as of PHP 5.3.0.
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version you are using ?

mysqli_master_query() function has been DEPRECATED and REMOVED as of PHP 5.3.0.

Refer : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-master-query.php